# Change color with pressure

Tags: animation, materials, node-editor, animation-nodes, force-fields

Heyyy,
I want to have an animation auf colored balls/bubbles like here in the Houdini tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grPVW0vK6PE

Is there any similar solution in Blender? Maybe where the object is changing it's material when some force is applied on the object with forcefields for example.
I assume its done with geometry nodes but I never really worked with them and don't know what to search exactly :D

(I also tried to rebuild everything with houdini, but I don't have the render engine or the full version of it haha so I sadly cant complete it)

Thx in advanced guys :)